# Screen mounting twice when I try to navigate to other screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I set up my navigation like the Authentication flows of react-navigation (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html)

When it doesn't have a data stored in Asyncstorage It will redirect to the Log in screen but when I try to press the Sign up button in the Log in screen, it flashes the sign up screen quickly then go back again to the Log in screen then after that if I press the sign up button again it will work. I used this.props.navigation.navigate to change screens and I am also using SwitchNavigator.

I added 'console.log('1')' to the componentDidMount() of my Log in screen to test it. It displays 1 and when I pressed the sign up button it prints 1 again.

[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3ejg.png)

Comment: Hi nekooo, please include your code so that we can help debug. Thanks!